# getting a value from a form

Tags: javascript, forms

IM trying to test to see if my code is set up right to access the text value of a form. im just trying to access text value and then use Console.log to confirm that its getting that far.

here is my code(

```
<body>
        <form id="form">
        <input type="text" id="item">
        <button class="Btn add item">Add item</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("item").onclick = function() {
           var output = document.getElementById("item").value;

           console.log(output);
          }
        </script>
      </body>
```

When I run it in the Dev tools in chrome nothing happens. No error and console doesn't log the value I entered into the form.

Comment: When you click the #item textfield is empty. So it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var output = document.getElementById("item").innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is incorrect names of the ID-attributes. Be careful!

```
<body>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <button id="button"  type="button">Add item</button>
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
        var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
        console.log("Your string is: " +  str);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag lacks the value attribute and has no default value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to log the value when the button is clicked rather than the input. Try this out:

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="item"/>
  <button id="btn" class="Btn add item" type="button">Add item</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("item").value;
    console.log(output);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are looking for from your example, but if you want your value to be logged as you type it can be done this way :

```
    <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button class="Btn add item">Add item</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('item').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        var output = e.target.value
        console.log(output)
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Markus Zeller** said, when your input tag has no value, `console.log` will show a space.
Try entering any number of characters, then out focus, then click on the input again, you will see it displays exactly the value of the input tag you just entered.